# 添字[]を使わずに回文判定をしたい

Tags: c

タイトルにも書いたように、回文を判定するプログラムを添え字ありきで作ることはできたのですが、添字を使わず、`*` だけでどのようにプログラムをすればいいのかがわかりませんでした。

`const char str[]` を添え字を使わずに `char *str` で表すにはどうすればいいでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

とりあえず、添字ありのプログラムを以下に示します。

```
#include<stdio.h>

int palindrome(const char str[])
{
    int l,r;
    r=0;
    while(str[r]!='\0'){
       r++;
    }
    r--;
    l=0;
    while(l<=r){
       if(str[l]!=str[r]){
         return 0;
       }
       r--;
       l++;
    }
    return 1;
}

#define MAXSTRLEN 128

int main(void)
{
    char str[MAXSTRLEN];
    printf("Input Word: ");
    scanf("%s", str);

    if (palindrome(str))
        printf("%sは回文です。\n", str);
    else
        printf("%sは回文ではありません。\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str[i]`は`*(str+i)`に書き換え可能です。
※`char *str`でなく`char str[]`のままでも`str[i]`は`*(str+i)`に書き換えられます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。同じ原理で他のも修正し直したら、きちんと実行できました。また、今回のことは初めて知ったので、勉強となりました。