# C言語のソースコードの一部内容の読解（解釈）がわかりません

Tags: c

[添字[]を使わずに回文判定をしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/73006/%e6%b7%bb%e5%ad%97%e3%82%92%e4%bd%bf%e3%82%8f%e3%81%9a%e3%81%ab%e5%9b%9e%e6%96%87%e5%88%a4%e5%ae%9a%e3%82%92%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

の、質問文にありますソースコードで、

```
   r--;
   l++;
}
return 1;
```

の部分の読解（解釈）がわからず困っています。
これは、日本語にするとどういった処理が行われているのでしょうか。

Comment: 他の部分がわかるのなら、なぜその4行がわからないのかを教えてください。

Comment: 他の部分は大体流れがわかるのですが、ここだけは文字ではわかっていても頭で処理が理解できませんでした（今はわかりました）

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`r`は`right`の頭文字で、文字列の右端(末尾)側のインデックスでしょう。
`l`は`left`の頭文字で、文字列の左端(先頭)側のインデックスでしょう。

ループの最初の判定`if(str[l]!=str[r]){`で両方のインデックスで指し示す文字が同じだったので、次に比較する文字のインデックスに移行するために、`r`(右端(末尾)側)のインデックスをデクリメント`--`して1つ左に移動させます、`l`(左端(先頭)側)のインデックスも同様にインクリメント`++`して1つ右に移動させます。

文字列の両端から順に比較していって、真ん中までのすべての文字が同じであったならば`while(l<=r){`のループが終了し、`return 1;`で回文であったことを示す戻り値で関数を終了します。

質問に抽出されていない参照先記事の部分`if(str[l]!=str[r]){`で、比較した文字が違っていたら`return 0;`で回文では無かったことを示す戻り値で関数を終了します。